# Displaying the blog pagetitle as a url in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a blog page where the blogs are inserted from admin panel and blog title will be inserted into new column as separated by " - " if there are spaces between the page titles.For example if the page title is " welcome to something " then in the database it is will be inserted into two columns. In once column it will be inserted as same and in other column it will be inserted as welcome-to-something.

when clicking on readmore button i need to display in url as (www.example.com/blob/article/welcome-to-something) in this format i need to display the url.

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('blogs_model');          
        $data["records2"] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_blogs($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data['mainpage'] = "blog";
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }

    public function article()
    {
      $this->load->model('blogs_model');
      $data['records2']= $this->blogs_model->getblogsdata($this->uri->segment(3));                
      $data['mainpage']='blogs';
      $this->load->view('templates/templatess',$data);

    }
```

Model:

```
function get_all_blogs()
{
    $this->db->select('B.*');
    $this->db->from('blogs AS B');
    $this->db->where(array('B.status'=>1));
    $this->db->order_by("position", "asc");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function getblogsdata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('blogs.*');       
    $this->db->from('blogs');
    $this->db->where(array('blogs.blog_id'=>$id));
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
  <div class="col-md-9 blogs"> 
            <?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
            <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>          
                <div class="blog1">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" class="testimonials1"/>
                    <h3 class="heading1"><?php echo $r->blog_title;?></h3>
                    <div class="blogtext1 read">                        
                        <?php echo $r->description;?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->blog_id ;?>" class="read_more7" target="_blank" >Read More</a>
                </div>

            <?php endforeach ;endif;?>
            <div class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></div> 
            </div>
```

blogs table

blog_id | blog_title              | blogtitle 
1         welcome to something      welcome-to-something

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->the_url_with_ '-'_ column_name;?>" class="read_more7" target="_blank" >Read More</a>

check and tell what it shows

Comment: @Exprator tried that but it is not displaying any data

Comment: @Exprator getting this error in that page 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/blogs_model.php

Comment: what is you column name where you are saving the hyphened url?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r->blogtitle;?>" class="read_more7" target="_blank" >Read More</a>

Comment: @Exprator yes tried the same one only i got that error trying to get property of non object in model i am getting the error

Comment: can you print the result and see if blogtitle is getting displayed in the result or not, or is it coming in array and not object

Comment: In the url it is displaying as www.example.com/blog/article/welcome-to something

Comment: But the issue unable to fecth the data from database

Comment: yeah because you need to fetch it with the blogtitle, and not id. change your query and search by where blogtitle='something'

Comment: @Exprator $this->db->where(array('blogs.blogtitle'=>$id));

Comment: Getting the same error message no change

Comment: can you print this $this->uri->segment(3) and also print the $q->result and see what both returns

Comment: Solved the problem

Comment: The data is printing but getting these error message 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/blogs_model.php

Line Number: 139

Comment: which is line 139, post it here

Comment: function update_counter($slug)
    {
        $this->db->where('blog_id', urldecode($slug));
        $this->db->select('ne_views'); $count = $this->db->get('blogs')->row();
        $this->db->where('blog_id', urldecode($slug)); this is the line
        $this->db->set('ne_views', ($count->ne_views + 1));
        $this->db->update('blogs');
    }

Comment: i am not getting anything from here. just paste the line 139. edit your question and put it there

Comment: $this->db->where('blog_id', urldecode($slug));

Comment: you need to pass it in an array like this $this->db->where(array('blogs.blog_id'=>$id));

Comment: As of now it is like that only in getblogsdata

Comment: bro change the column and the value, come on man understand a little, change the name accrodingly what you need

Comment: changed everything instead of id i have placed blogtittle but the issue is i am not able to get the count .If anyone opens the blog then it will get the count and update in the database but it is not working after changing

Comment: $this->db->where(array('blogs.blogtitle'=>urldecode($slug)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
function getblogsdata($id,$slug)
{
    $this->db->select('blogs.*');       
    $this->db->from('blogs');
    $this->db->where(array('blogs.blogtitle'=>$id));
    $this->db->where(array('blogs.blogtitle' => $slug));
    $this->db->order_by("ne_views", "asc");         
    $q=$this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r->blogtitle;?>" class="read_more7" target="_blank" >Read More</a>
```